# Replace part of URL with variable

Tags: python, json, url

I need to replace `Start_date` and `End_date` in a specific URL with variables, say `x = start_date`, and `y = end_date`.
The part of the called URL is `/energy?startDate=2023-06-01&endDate=2023-06-30`.

I would like to have parts with `startDate=2023-06-01` and `endDate=2023-06-30` defined as a variable, so it would be able to generate API responses for different time periods. Let's say like this

```py
X = "startDate=2023-06-01" # Start date 
Y = "endDate=2023-06-30"   # End date
```

and new URL = `/energy?f"{x}"&f"{y}"&api_key/`

But I somehow can't get the link to work calling variables - in this case string constants.

I can't make this API response work with these variables, though JSON response works with the original URL link.

Comment: Check if this helps: [Output formatting in Python: replacing several %s with the same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982949/output-formatting-in-python-replacing-several-s-with-the-same-variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add params to given URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this question/answer: [Output formatting in Python: replacing several %s with the same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982949/output-formatting-in-python-replacing-several-s-with-the-same-variable)

you can do:

```
fromDate = '2023-12-01'
toDate = '2023-12-31'
url = f'/energy?%20timeUnit=DAY&format=json&startDate={fromDate}&endDate={toDate}&api_key/'
print(url)

fromDate = '2024-01-01'
toDate = '2024-01-31'
url = '/energy?%20timeUnit=DAY&format=json&startDate={f}&endDate={t}&api_key/'.format(f=fromDate, t=toDate)
print(url)
```

output:

```
/energy?%20timeUnit=DAY&format=json&startDate=2023-12-01&endDate=2023-12-31&api_key/
/energy?%20timeUnit=DAY&format=json&startDate=2024-01-01&endDate=2024-01-31&api_key/
```

or, to see if *live*: https://onlinegdb.com/owDxKVzvkH